# Shell option "OPTIONNAME" is not working properly with my script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script that and i would like to print out the message if particular command line flags are provided while running that script. For example, here is my bash script

```
while getopts ":hi:l:1:2:U:O:s:p:5:3:qQm:M:I:X:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    i)
    index_folder=$OPTARG # Input folder
     ;;
    l)
     lib_type=$OPTARG # Library type
     ;;
    1)
    left_reads+=("$OPTARG") # Left reads
     ;;
    2)
    right_reads=("$OPTARG") # Right reads
    ;;
    U)
    single_reads+=("$OPTARG") # single end reads
     ;;
    O)
    bam_out=$OPTARG # Samoutput file
     ;;
    s)
    sra_id=$OPTARG # SRA ID
     ;;
    p)
    num_threads=$OPTARG # Number of threads
     ;;
    5)
    five_trim=$OPTARG # 5' trim
     ;;
    3)
    three_trim=$OPTARG # 3' trim
     ;;
    q)
    quality_33=$OPTARG # Phred 33 
     ;;
    Q)
    quality_64=$OPTARG # Phread 64
     ;;
    m)
    min_intl=$OPTARG # Minimum intron length
     ;;
    M)
    max_intl=$OPTARG # Maximum intron length
     ;;
    t)
    tra_as=$OPTARG # Report alignments tailored for transcript assemblers including StringTie
     ;;
    c)
    tra_cuff=$OPTARG # Report alignments tailored specifically for Cufflinks
     ;;
  esac
done


if [ ! -z $left_reads ] && [ ! -z $right_reads ]; then
    echo "original"

elif [ ! -z $left_reads ] && [ ! -z $right_reads ] && [ ! -o $quality_33 ];
then
    echo "quality"
fi
```

And when i try to run like this. It prints correctly

```
sh test.sh -i index -l "F" -1 reads_1.fq -1 e_coli_1000_1.fq -2 reads_2.fq -2 e_coli_1000_2.fq -p 2 -O final_bam -5 10 -3 10 -m 20 -M 200 
original
```

However, when i try to include an extra option (corresponds to the second conditional - "quality"), it still prints the first output

```
sh Hisat2_align.sh -i index -l "F" -1 reads_1.fq -1 e_coli_1000_1.fq -2 reads_2.fq -2 e_coli_1000_2.fq -p 2 -O final_bam -5 10 -3 10 -m 20 -M 200 -q
original
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: [mcve] - your code is far from minimal and I'm not even sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. according to your optstring, `-q` does not take an argument, so `quality_33=$OPTARG` assigns the empty string to that variable

   - declare `quality_33=0` before the while, and in that case branch use `quality_33=1`
2. since you are using `elif` to test for `-q`, and the `if` conditional was true, you won't ever see "quality"
3. the test `[ ! -o $quality_33 ]` will never be true: the variable is empty, so bash sees
   `[ ! -o ]` -- in this case, "-o" is taken as a plain string not an operator, and a plain non-empty string is always true. Then you negate that result. When using single brackets, **always** quote your variables:

   ```
   elif [ ! -z "$left_reads" ] && [ ! -z "$right_reads" ] && [ "$quality_33" -eq 1 ]
   ```

Comment: Does `getopts` actually reset `OPTARG` when reading an option without an argument?

Comment: Yes. An example: `set -- -a 1 -b; OPTIND=1; while getopts "a:b" opt; do echo ">$opt< >$OPTARG<"; done`

Comment: Interesting. That behavior doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: I did declare `quality_33=0` before the while loop and added the `quality_33=1` before the first `if` and changed my `elif` as you said, but it still didn't worked.

Comment: Well, the `if` condition succeeded, **so you never get to the elif block**.

Comment: But i should get to the elif when i run with `-q` on the command line? `sh Hisat2_align.sh -i index -l "F" -1 reads_1.fq -1 e_coli_1000_1.fq -2 reads_2.fq -2 e_coli_1000_2.fq -p 2 -O final_bam -5 10 -3 10 -m 20 -M 200 -q`

Comment: You also provide $left_read and $right_reads,   so you branch into the `if`case, not `elif`. Follow your own logic.\

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for your patience.